# How to completely replace the action bar of AppCompatActivity with custom action bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I am absolute beginner to Android. Now I am learning how to layout an Android app. So I started to use navigation drawer to together with toolbar. Now I am creating a custom action without default features. But it is not working.

This is my main activity layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my toolbar layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is my activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

But when I start the activity, title and option to view menu items are included in the action bar even though I did not define in the layout like in screenshot.

[image]

So what I want to do is I want to completely replace the action bar with my custom toolbar and I want to erase the default behaviours.

So I tried to remove the title in this way in activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

But it is throwing error

This is the logcat

```
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa614a908)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.waiyanhein.todo.todo/com.waiyanhein.todo.todo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.waiyanhein.todo.todo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
01-23 12:28:45.945 2972-2972/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-23 12:28:45.961 2972-2975/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 249K, 13% free 2610K/2988K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 18ms
01-23 12:28:45.961 386-801/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.waiyanhein.todo.todo/.MainActivity
01-23 12:28:46.177 386-801/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1205K, 46% free 8703K/16012K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
01-23 12:28:46.209 386-402/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 149K, 40% free 9732K/16012K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
01-23 12:28:46.241 386-402/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 33% free 10832K/16012K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
01-23 12:28:46.241 386-402/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 13.126MB for 2536932-byte allocation
01-23 12:28:46.301 386-401/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 29% free 13307K/18492K, paused 59ms, total 59ms
01-23 12:28:46.309 386-389/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 29% free 13307K/18492K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 10ms
```

So my first question is why is that throwing error when I customize the action bar in activity? Is there anything wrong with my code? My second question is how to completely replace the action bar with my custom one as I asked above.

Comment: Call `setSupportActionBar()` before `getSupportActionBar()`, and specify your `AppTheme` on the `<activity>` or `<application>` in the manifest.

Comment: Yes It worked. But how to completely replace with custom one ?

Comment: How to remove see more option items option at the right side of the action bar ?

Comment: Remove the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method override. You can probably get rid of the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method, too.

Comment: Remove from activity ? But I want to show it when user click on the menu button of mobile phone. I only want to remove it from action bar.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Don't set the Toolbar as the support ActionBar. Just go with no ActionBar, and modify the Toolbar directly as needed.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is happening because you're attempting to access and modify the support `ActionBar` on an `Activity` with a `NoActionBar` theme before you've set the `Toolbar` as the substitute. However, given your desired Options Menu behavior, you don't want to do that.

If an `Activity` has an `ActionBar` implementation, its Options Menu will automatically be created as a dropdown menu in the `ActionBar` itself. Since you're using a `NoActionBar` theme, just don't set the `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar`, and the Options Menu will revert to the old style.

Comment: Aww. :) . sorry . Thanks for your answer. I will  green up this answer.